# Need click to trigger after appending element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see the below code:

HTML:

```
<p>Click this paragraph.</p>
```

JS:

```
$("p").live("click", function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");  

    $("body").append("<p>This was newly added. this has also click</p>")
});
```

Now the element is appending correctly. But the click is not triggering for the appended element. If i am using `live` instead of `on` its working fine. But live was depreciated. What to do.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzLsa7uf/4/)

Comment: use jquery migrate library

Comment: `$(document).on('click', 'p', handler);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the delegate style for [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
>
> - events Type: String One or more space-separated event types and    optional namespaces, such as "click" or "keydown.myPlugin".
> - selector Type: String A selector string to filter the descendants of    the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is
>     null    or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the 
>     selected element.
> - data Type: Anything Data to be passed to the handler in event.data    when an event is triggered.
> - handler Type: Function( Event eventObject [, Anything extraParameter    ] [, ... ] ) A function to execute when the event is
>     triggered. The    value false is also allowed as a shorthand for a
>     function that simply    does return false.

As you don't want to pass data, you can write in form:

```
$(body).on('click', 'p', handler)
```

which omits the data param.

```js
$("body").on("click", "p", function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");  

    $("body").append("<p>This was newly added. this has also click</p>")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click this paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change it to this:

```
$("body").on("click", "p", function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");  

    $("body").append("<p>This was newly added. this has also click</p>")
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzLsa7uf/5/)

You don't want to use `p` as that will only work on the `p` elements that are already on the page, so new ones that you append wont work.

If you use the `body` and set it so when you click on a `p`, do the function, it will work.